# I am in Git/BitBucket Hell

Tags: git, intellij-idea, bitbucket

I am a novice Git/BitBucket user and I have a big problem.  I made some coding changes and did an initial commit/ push back to the repository from my local branch to the remote branch.  Since that time have made many changes but only committed and pushed from local to remote but never merged with master.  Stash will only provide the last committed changes which doesn't include the initial commit.  Before I had a chance to fix the issue, my laptop crashed and I lost all of my local changes that I needed to merge.

I see that I can download the initial commit to a zip file.  I should be able to take all the changes from the other remote commits and apply them in order to get back to a workable master copy(tedious but necessary).  However, I am unsure how I would go about "checking out" the zipped intial commit so that I have a baseline to work on and eventually merge to the master.  I am using Intellij 20.20.2 as the IDE.

If there is a better option please let me know.

Comment: Better ask for help in chat, your question in it's current form is not in a good shape for this site.

Comment: If you pushed any git state to a remote, that remote contains all commits that you pushed, so all parent commits of any branch, including any initial commit. It is this unclear in you question where your problem lies. Maybe you can use a terminal to run git commands to clone your repository from Stash, and paste the command log to your question here, it will be easier to understand your issue.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear.  When I look at the last commit via Bitbucket, it will only show the modules that I changed.  So are you saying that even though the commit only shows what I changed, the commit itself contains all of the modules that were unchanged as well?  So when I do a clone, I should be up to date to the last commit even though I did not merge with the master?

Comment: When you clone, you get a complete branch with all parents, including the initial state (initial commit). Bitbucket should also have a view to show all those commits. If you pushed a branch, you can get that branch back completely. The situation of merge with master is difficult to understand from your description. But whatever you pushed, you can get back, completely.